# Converting sequence expression to a string in R plot label

Tags: r, plot, label

```
ab <- 1:4
plot(ab, main = paste("value",ab))
```

The above produces

[image]

Whereas I want the label to show exactly like `value 1:4`. I know I can do this by tweaking the `paste` function something like `paste0("value ",ab[1],":", ab[4])`. But there must be a simpler way and also sometimes `ab` is just a single number, so I want something consistent that works for both cases. I also tried with `expression` and `bquote`, but can't figure out a way. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `range(ab)` and a second `paste` (with `collapse=':'`) to get this result. <s>For the case where `ab` is a single value, I had to use `ifelse`.</s>

EDIT: a slightly shorter solution using `unique` instead of `ifelse` to treat for the case with a single value

```
ab <- 1:4
plot(ab, main = paste("value", paste(unique(range(ab)), collapse = ':')))
```

[image]

If `ab = 1`:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, this works. But, I am still wondering if there are any other ways to treat `1:n` as a string and make the code sleeker.